# Printing an SSRS report in Landscape mode from Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have a Windows Forms application that has a `textbox`, a `button`, and 3 `ReportViewer`. The 3 `ReportViewer` boxes are hidden. When you enter a `ShopOrder` into the textbox and click on the button, it will automatically pass the Shop order value as a parameter to all 3 reports, render the report, and once the rendering is complete, render the report as EMF file, print the report.

[I am using this link as a guide to print SSRS reports automatically from a Windows Forms application.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx)

I have a few variances in my application because I am using `ServerReports` in my `ReportViewer` and not `LocalReport`. But after all these changes, my application prints them all out with no problems.

But the only issue I have is, I am not able to set my page orientation to `Landscape`, even though the orientation on my report is Landscape.

So I thought maybe I need to set the `deviceInfo` variable's `PageWidth` and `PageHeight` variables accordingly, so this is what the `deviceInfo` variable has:

```
string deviceInfo =
    @"<DeviceInfo>
        <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
        <PageWidth>11in</PageWidth>
        <PageHeight>8.5in</PageHeight>
        <MarginTop>0.25in</MarginTop>
        <MarginLeft>0.25in</MarginLeft>
        <MarginRight>0.25in</MarginRight>
        <MarginBottom>0.25in</MarginBottom>
    </DeviceInfo>";
```

I have two `Export` functions: `Export` and `ExportLandscape`. The code snippet above is a part of `ExportLandscape`. When I call `ExportLandscape`, my report still prints in Portrait.

I tried just completely removing the Page setup options from my `DeviceInfo` variable and made it just say the `OutputFormat`. That didn't do it either.

Is there anything else I need to change for my report to print in Landscape? What am I missing?

It is also worth noting that, out of my 3 reports, 2 of them print in Landscape and 1 prints in Portrait. So I would really like for my application to just print it in whatever page settings the report is in. I just tried getting the report's page size and report's margins and setting those to my `DeviceInfo` variable [as suggested here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brianhartman/2009/02/27/manually-printing-a-report/). STILL NO LUCK!!

I just tried adding a breakpoint at the `Export(ReportViewer report)` function and stepped through. When I get the `report.ServerReport.GetDefaultPageSettings().PaperSize` in the immediate window, I see this:

```
{[PaperSize Letter Kind=Letter Height=1100 Width=850]}
    Height: 1100
    Kind: Letter
    PaperName: "Letter"
    RawKind: 1
    Width: 850
```

This makes me feel like even though my report is set to landscape (height = 8.5in and Width = 11in), my application does not seem to recognize it.

**Important Update:**

The printer I am printing to has 2 paper trays. When I print a portrait report, it takes it from the default tray with the default paper size (tray 2). But when my application sends the landscape report to print, the printer tries to get a paper out of tray 1. When I load tray 1 with the same paper that is in tray 2, it asks me to enter a width and height of the paper. The printer does not seem to understand when I tell it to print it in landscape. Or rather, the printer thinks this is some new setting that it does not know about. When I enter 11 for width and 8.5 for height, it prints landscape data on a portrait paper.

To make myself clearer, the data is getting printed with a width of 11 and height of 8.5. AKA, only 75% of the data gets printed. The rest gets pushed out of the page because the page is still being oriented in portrait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a suitable `PageSettings` for the `PrintDocument` which is used for printing. You need to apply some changes to code of that [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms252091(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to be able to print in different paper size or page layout.

First you need to create a suitable `PageSettings`, for example if you have set the default page setting for your report to be landscape:

```
var report = reportViewer1.LocalReport;
var pageSettings = new PageSettings();
pageSettings.PaperSize = report.GetDefaultPageSettings().PaperSize;
pageSettings.Landscape = report.GetDefaultPageSettings().IsLandscape;
pageSettings.Margins = report.GetDefaultPageSettings().Margins;
```

or if you want to create a new page setting:

```
var pageSettings = new PageSettings();
pageSettings.Landscape = true;
pageSettings.PaperSize = reportViewer1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Cast<PaperSize>()
    .Where(x => x.Kind == PaperKind.A4).First();
```

Then use the `pageSetting` when creating the deviceInfo:

```
string deviceInfo =
    $@"<DeviceInfo>
        <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
        <PageWidth>{pageSettings.PaperSize.Width * 100}in</PageWidth>
        <PageHeight>{pageSettings.PaperSize.Height * 100}in</PageHeight>
        <MarginTop>{pageSettings.Margins.Top * 100}in</MarginTop>
        <MarginLeft>{pageSettings.Margins.Left * 100}in</MarginLeft>
        <MarginRight>{pageSettings.Margins.Right * 100}in</MarginRight>
        <MarginBottom>{pageSettings.Margins.Bottom * 100}in</MarginBottom>
    </DeviceInfo>";
```

And at last, use the same pageSettings with `PrintDocument`:

```
PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
printDoc.DefaultPageSettings = pageSettings;
```

I've created an extension method to make it easier to print the report easily by calling `Print()` or `Print(PageSettings)`. You can find it here: [Print RDLC Report without showing the ReportViewer](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/print-rdlc-report-without-showing-the-reportviewer/)

Comment: I am about to try this out now.

Comment: So I encountered a few hiccups in this solution: 1. I have a separate class with the `Print` functionalities in it and this class does not have a constructor for `ReportViewer`. Just `Report`, `LocalReport`, and `ServerReport`. I tried doing it on the `ServerReport` constructor AND the `Report` constructor. Neither have the `PrinterSettings` property. 2. `reportViewer1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes` does not have a `cast` property. Continued in next comment....

Comment: But I used yours as an example to create a separate `PaperSize` variable and if the report is landscape, I set the `PaperSize` variable width and height accordingly and use this variable for my printing purposes. It now prints in landscape. The only problem I have is, the report is getting squeezed in a bit. My actual report is designed to fit a landscape paper exactly, but for some reason, the application squeezes it in. I can look at further and figure out what's going on now. Thank you so much for bringing me this far! :)

Comment: I didn't have any problem printing the report. I just added another way of creating the `PageSetting` based on the default page setting of the report, since you have setup the default page setting to be landscape, you can use it. (Just for your information `Cast` is a linq extension method in `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: Also I created an extension method called `Print` for `LocalReport`. You can easily use `Print()` or `Print(PageSettings)`. You can find it [here](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/print-rdlc-report-without-showing-the-reportviewer/).

Comment: Beautiful, thank you so much! You've been very helpful :)

Comment: Will the code on your link work if I change the `LocalReport` to `ServerReport` instead? This is a much more streamlined clean way of doing it and I wanted to try it out.

Comment: You're welcome :) At the moment I don't have access to Reporting Services, I'll look at that as soon as I have access to SSRS.

Comment: The only thing I had to change in your code was the `report.Render` function. `ServerReport` has a different `Render()` function than a `LocalReport` does. I changed that and the report prints in Landscape perfectly. Again, thank you!